# Create a blueprint from a AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

When creating a new AWS Lambda function, several blueprints are suggested, e.g. Blank Function, kinesis-firehose-syslog-to-json, etc. I have an existing function, and I'd like it to become one of the blueprints, so I can easily clone it. Feel free to suggest solutions which use the AWS CLI
to add blueprints or clone functions. [image]

Comment: Blueprints are just a "getting started" convenience.  You can't create your own.  As for the alternatives, read the documentation.  For example, downloading the zip file of an existing function so you can reuse it, using aws-cli [is documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html).

Comment: I would really like to see this functionality also, for ease in replication of Alexa Skills' lambdas to multiple regions. The more that they expand to other regions (e.g. UK, Canada, India, and most recently Australia), the less scaleable the existing Lambda workflow is. Perhaps AWS will create a multi-region replication option for Lambdas? (EDIT: Also, there is a difference between the Lambda function and the code that it runs. so the zip file and code duplication via a repo is orthogonal to the blueprints issue)

Answer (score 2):

Blueprints are "suggested templates" that are created and made available from AWS. There is no facility to manage your own Blueprints within AWS.

It sounds like you are looking to create your own template, or skeleton code for being able to easily create new lambda functions from. In that case I would set up your skeleton project and push it to a source code repo, such as [github](https://github.com). This will allow you to clone your repo anytime you want to create a new function.